# r.out.xyz not working

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

I've got QGIS 2.8.1 - Wien on my system and often use the Grass tool r.out.xyz. Two of my colleagues have recently installed QGIS 2.18.12, which shows both Grass and Grass7 processing tools. Grass7 doesn't seem to have r.out.xyz (although I thing it should acoording to the [reference manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/raster.html)). The Grass processing tools don't work altogether, even when changing the Grass and Msys folder locations in the processing options. I've installed 2.18.12 myself (next to the 2.8.1 version), and indeed there is no Grass7 r.out.xyz tool and the Grass version does't work. In 2.8.1 the Grass r.out.xyz fortunately still works. Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: In my QGIS 2.18.2, `r.out.xyz` also isn't available for GRASS7 but is for GRASS. What you can try doing is going into the QGIS GRASS directory (e.g. `/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass/description/`), copy the "r.out.xyz" text file and paste this into the GRASS7 directory (e.g. `/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description/`). Then restart QGIS, you should find the tool in the _Processing Toolbox_. Try running it and see if it works.

Comment: If yes, we can submit it as "pull request" to the repo of QGIS

Comment: This solution seems to work fine!

Comment: The comment by joseph solved my problem too by copying and pasting the r.out.xyz.txt file to the grass7 folder. Now i can add it to my modeler!

Comment: @Joseph perhaps you or the asker can write up an answer that describes precisely how this question was resolved.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Thanks but will let the asker write up an answer when they get a chance :)